# Test explorer not detecting the test cases in vs2015

Tags: visual-studio, selenium-webdriver

I created one console application in VS2015. After that I added one feature file and created step definition for that feature. I add spec flow and spec run from nuget. The issue is the test explorer not detecting the test cases.

Comment: And your code looks like what?

Comment: I think the text explorer only works for unit tests??? You have to compile the project before they will show up.